# Unable to resolve contact name from number

Tags: android

I'm using a Android Wildfire and I used the following code to lookup the contact name of an existing phone number.

```
private String getContactNameFromNumber(String number) {
    String[] projection = new String[] { Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME, 
            Contacts.Phones.NUMBER };

    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, Uri.encode(number));

    Log.d(TAG, contactUri.toString());

    // query time
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null,
            null, null);

    // if the query returns 1 or more results
    // return the first result
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME));
        Log.d(TAG, name);
        return name;
    }

    // return null if no match was found
    return null;
}
```

I am unable to resolve the contact name. I'm new to this topic any assistance will be appreciated. Many thanks in advance. The logcat output shows the following

```
11-14 13:45:35.879: DEBUG/Test(3342): content://contacts/phones/filter/%2B919773653345
```

Comment: Are you sure the number you're searching does exists in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method of getting the contacts is deprecated. You should use [ContactsContract.PhoneLookup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html) unless you're programming for older phones.

As LucaB said, the Cursor should probably be closed.

Comment: Yup I noticed it and now the cursor is closed.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you don't call the contacts correctly.
Try changing

```
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, Uri.encode(number));
```

to

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey)
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, projection, null, null, null);
try {
    c.moveToFirst();
    String displayName = c.getString(0);
} finally {
    c.close();
}
```

Comment: My API Level is 1.6, I don't have Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI